# How to convert a WOFF2 webfont into a TTF desktop font?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, save, file-format

Googling leads me to `everythingfonts . com` which is down, at least for the last two days but it may have been down for a while.

Googling `"woff2 to ttf" -everythingfonts` has very few results surprisingly, all of which are useless.

**How can I convert a (WOFF2) webfont into a (True Type) desktop font?**

Comment: Make sure you have a licence to use the font you're converting.

Comment: Webfonts are often a subset of the actual full font. It may not even make sense to try and convert it.

Comment: @DA01 I've never heard that before. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt yes. Lots of fonts are HUGE in terms of full character sets...especially OT fonts which can support many languages, special characters, swashes, ligatures, emojis, etc. You don't want to force people to download all the cyrillic characters if the site is in English, for example, so the font can be sub-setted to produce a smaller file size. Granted, maybe *often* isn't the right term there. I should have stated *sometimes*.

Comment: @DA01 Ah. Yes, I see what you mean by subset now. I was thinking you were referring to Bold, Italic, Book, etc (which is the case with some desktop fonts, but which I've never seen with webfonts). Yes of course they strip out unneeded characters.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt well typically Bold and Italic would be two separate font files...even with web fonts.

Comment: @DA01 No you misunderstand. Sometimes different font weights are tied to a main font file and cannot be used separately. (Also, I assume you meant desktop fonts.)

Comment: @djangoreinhardt do you have an example? I've never heard of that. Bold is always a separate font file. Look at Google fonts for examples.

Comment: @DA01Again you misunderstand me. I'll try again: Sometimes different font weights are stored *in separate files* that cannot be used without the *main font file*. So for example: Times Regular works fine on its own, but Times Bold will not work unless Times Regular is present. Not all fonts, but some desktop ones. I hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: @DA01 Also, it's worth noting that you can have files like TTC (True Type Font Collections) which do allow several fonts to be included in one file: http://www.wikiwand.com/en/TrueType#TrueType_Collection

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt oh! I see. I've never run into that before myself. The bundle fonts make sense...still separate files, just bundled into one wrapper file.

Comment: Whether a webfont (of any format) contains a full glyph-set or a subset has absolutely no impact on converting/decoding.  Conversion tools don't get confused, they just convert the existing glyphs.  I've never seen a dialog box that said `Does not make enough sense; Refusing to convert...` or any such nonsense.

Comment: @spiral who on earth needs a license?

Comment: @BjørsonÅlmer maybe I should have rephrased: make sure the license you own allows the usage you intent. Most fonts (even free ones, even open source ones) include a licence which details what you're allowed or not to do with it.

Answer (score 29):

On linux you can go to https://github.com/google/woff2 and compile that, then you'll have two utilities, one for compressing fonts to woff2 format and the other to decompress woff2 fonts to ttf.

Comment: On Mac: `brew install woff2`

Comment: The command is `woff2_decompress file.woff2`

Comment: For all fonts in folder (bash): `for file in *.woff2; do woff2_decompress "$file"; done`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the WOFF2-to-TTF converter on Everything Fonts:

https://everythingfonts.com/woff2-to-ttf

Comment: This worked. Thanks

Comment: Excellent. Just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator or http://onlinefontconverter.com they both work well and the sites are running OK

Comment: The webfoot generator does not allow uploading woff files; the online font converter is broken.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good converter on a popular site, https://cloudconvert.com/woff2-to-ttf .

Comment: This one actually preserved the metadata as well!

Answer (score 0):

You contact the foundry or vendor from which you licenced the original WOFF and ask for/pay for the desktop version.

WOFF is a compressed format, so you cannot get the original desktop font from it.

Comment: Not true.  A `woff` file is literally just a wrapper for a `ttf` or `otf`, and there are countless utilities that can convert back to the target format of your choice.  Like any of the above free services online, desktop software such as TransType, free command-line tools, free python scripts or javascripts for offline use, etc.  Now if you are making a statement about the legality of doing so, that is another story, for another question, one whose answer varies greatly depending on many factors.

Comment: You can get a workable ttf or otf from it, but since there is some compression ocurring, you cannot get the ORIGINAL, uncompressed font from it.

Comment: That's not how compression works :) You compress and decompress, to end up with the same file. Most "original" files which are used to generate woff files might be subsets or otherwise limited fonts, but you can always generate that "original" from a woff file.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a WOFF font, you probably only have a license to use it on a website. Desktop licenses-licenses to use it in printed media etc.-are sold separately. And foundries often don't allow conversion of fonts between formats for this very reason. We've seen the reverse of this question with the same issue.

If your boss asks you do to this tread very carefully, they and you could get sued for using a font for a purpose they haven't bought a license for-if they have a license to use a font on desktop, why don't they have the ttf or otf file the font designer prepared?